# Numpy dot product of a stacked array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 4 matrices representing (x, y) components of vectors v1 and v2. Therefore matrices are `x1, y1, x2, y2`.

Is it possible to compute dot product between arrays `[x1_i, y1_i], [x2_i, y2_i]`, where i is just a single element index in all four arrays (which are all the same shape).

My solution so far is to stack them together and for loop over:

```
v1 = np.stack((y1, x1), axis=0)
v2 = np.stack((y2, x2), axis=0)
s = np.zeros(v1.shape[1:])
for i in range(v1.shape[1]):
    for j in range(v1.shape[2]):
        s[i,j] = np.dot(v1[:,i,j], v2[:,i,j])
```

Best solution would be to do a dot product over both elements in axis=0 for all elements in v1 and v2. Something like np.dot(v1,v2,axis=0)

`x1.shape, y1.shape, x2.shape, y2.shape = (228, 192)`
`After stacking: v1.shape, v2.shape = (2, 228, 192)`

Code where i1 and i2 are arrays from image (SimpleITK).

```
    y1, x1 = np.gradients(i1)
    y2, x2 = np.gradients(i2)
    v1 = np.stack((y1, x1), axis=0)
    v2 = np.stack((y2, x2), axis=0)
    # this part is stupid
    s = np.zeros(v1.shape[1:])
    for i in range(v1.shape[1]):
        for j in range(v1.shape[2]):
            s[i,j] = np.dot(v1[:,i,j], v2[:,i,j])
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What are the shapes of v1, v2? Could you please add a dummy example input?

Comment: Please add an example of the output you want.

Comment: Having sample input and outputs here will help a lot. Also are x1, y1, x2 and y2 actually vectors not matrices?

Comment: `matmul/@` treats the leading dimensions as 'batch', and the last 2 as the `dot` part (with the sum-of-products on the last of A and 2nd to the last of B).  `einsum` lets you specify (almost) any combination of axes.

Comment: Or have you tried  `np.sum( v1*v2, axis=0)`?

Comment: `y1, x1 = np.gradients(i1)`. Is not very helpful in terms of showing what your data looks like. Something like `np.random.rand(11, 12)` is though. Writing an MCVE is not immediately intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
y1 * y2 + x1 * x2
```